# Laravel Create vs Save method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-injection

I have been using Laravel for quite a long time and I have always used `save()` method to populate my data. The main reason to use `save()` is, I want to save my time to declare the model's `fillable` array and all that stuff.

Now one of the main reason people use `fillables` is it prevents the application from `sql injections` as stated [here](https://medium.com/@kshitij206/laravel-mass-assignment-guarded-or-fillable-7c3a64b49ca6).
My question here is, which one is better, performance wise and security wise? It is obvious if I can access the code to change the model object and, I can easily access and modify the fillables array as well.

TIA

Comment: fillable got nothing to do with sql injection. And the post you link to is not stating that.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `Now one of the main reason people use fillables is it prevents the application from sql injections` is incorrect.

Fillable is a way of specifying which columns are allowed to be inserted in during mass assignment.

If you are using `save()` or `create` with `fillables`, laravel is going to use PDO parameter bindings internally which will prevent any SQL Injections.

`Create` is just another way of saving efforts if you want to insert multiple entries.